# Spring Security Oauth2 generating jsessiond even when create-session="stateless" is used

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring Security Oauth2  for authentication purpose in my application which is stateless . Below is the code snippet of spring config file
Also I have used `<%@ page session="false" %>` in all jsps.

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request -->
    <!-- parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http auto-config="true" create-session="stateless">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/test" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>`
```

Also I have created my own Authorization End point(/authorizeTest) as the one provided by Ouath2(/oauth/authorize) is putting AuthorizationRequest as session Attribute. Following is the code snippet for CustomAuthorizationEndPoint

```
<beans:bean id="customAuthorizationEndpoint"
    class="com.mkyong.common.controller.CustomAuthorizationEndpoint">
    <beans:property name="tokenGranter" ref="authorizationCodeTokenGranter" />
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <beans:property name="oAuth2RequestFactory" ref="customOAuth2RequestFactory" />
    <beans:property name="authorizationCodeServices"
        ref="inMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authorizationCodeTokenGranter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="tokenServices" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1"
        ref="authorizationCodeServices" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="clientDetails" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="3"
        ref="customOAuth2RequestFactory" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="customOAuth2RequestFactory"
    class="com.mkyong.common.controller.CustomOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="customAuthorizationRequest" ref="customAuthorizationRequest" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customAuthorizationRequest"
    class="com.mkyong.common.controller.CustomAuthorizationRequest">
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="authorizationCodeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />

</beans:bean>
```

But still I am getting jsession generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `create-session="stateless"` means that you are telling Spring Security not to create a session or store the authentication information for the user. It won't stop other libraries from creating a session if they feel the need to (oauth is a separate project).

I don't really understand why you are labelling the application as stateless, since you are using things like form login. If you don't allow a session to be created, how will somthing like the authorization code flow work? How is the authorization request cached and how will the server know the user is authenticated when they are redirected back to that request? The authentication will be lost since there is no session to tie it to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Like spring security provides support for stateless feature does Oauth 2 also provide any support given their are so many applications made now a days which are stateless.

Comment: The OAuth2 spec covers a lot of different use cases, not just the authorization code flow. If one client app is calling another, for example (a typical stateless situation) then there is the "client credentials" grant. It's not really clear from your question what you mean by "your application". You mostly seem to be referring to the interaction with the authorization server, which won't generally be stateless. OAuth2 is not an authentication spec, so you should clarify what you mean when you say you are using it "for authentication purposes". Which grant are you using? What's the use case.

Comment: I want to use Oauth2 for authenticating the users to login into my application. Here basically I am the client app and at the same time  also server(authorization-server and resource-server both) app.Use case behind this is currently I am generating the token through my code and saving it to database but what I want is Oauth2 to generate the tokens and validate against each user when it logins. Also I am currently using Authorization Code Grant type.

Comment: As per your suggestion I was able to use OAuth2 with client_credentials grant type for login into the application in a stateless manner. As per my understanding OAuth2 provides a way to access protected resources. In my case after logging in, any Ajax call will lead to a protected resource and hence I need to OAuth rest calls from client(javascript) side. For logging the user I was able to use     <oauth:rest-template> but how should I proceed for Ajax calls .

Comment: If your client is Javascript in a browser, then client credentials isn't a good idea. It is used for "trusted" clients which have their own client secret. It's still not really clear from your question why you need OAuth at all, rather than just authenticating as the user.

Comment: I am planning to use client credentials for the first time when user will login and there-after I will use Implicit for each ajax request for rest of application.